# Expresso Store - Create order programmically

Tags: expresso-store

Is there a way to create an Exp:resso Store order programmatically? Whats the minimum requirements for it to show in the dashboard and be a valid order.

Thanks
K

Answer (score 1):

Store is fairly abstracted when it comes to order data. Take a look in the database at the tables starting with `exp_store_order...` - these all come into play for a single order.

Also, if you want to record payments of any kind with an order, you'll need an entry in `exp_store_transactions`.

Comment: What about the Order Hash? Could I put any random 32 character alphanumeric value?

Comment: Yup. `ee()->load->helper('string'); $hash = random_string('unique');`.

Comment: No problem - and please mark this answer as accepted if you feel it answers your question.